# What do $this->escape() in zend framework actually do?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

I need help in understanding the actual actions of a helper function in Zend Framework.

I need someone to explain to me what `$this->escape($string)` actually does to the string passed to it before printing the string into the template.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`$this->escape()` escapes a string according to settings you can provide with `$this->setEscape('functionname')`, by default it is PHP's htmlspecialchars function.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.scripts.html

Answer (score 7):

It calls the [htmlspecialchars PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

> The translations performed are:
>
> - '&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
> - '"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;'
> - '<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
> - '>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'

Answer (score 1):

Over at the PiKe project we build a custom stream wrapper that automatically escapes all view variables to be safe by default against XSS, with a MINIMAL performance hit! You can still get the RAW value with:

`<?=~ $variable ?>`

Notice the "~" character. Checkout http://code.google.com/p/php-pike/wiki/Pike_View_Stream